# Modal won't close using OK button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want the first thing on my site to be a dialog which asks for a password, if the password length is less than 6, a span called password error shows, and you are not allowed to proceed. If the password length is bigger or equal to 6 you can press Ok and proceed. My problem is that nothing shows, and i can't proceed no matter what the length of the password is. Here is my code:

```
<div class="password_insert" title="Set your password"> 
    <span id="error"><b>Passwords error!</b></span>
    <span>New Password: </span>
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="ins_pass" /> <span>Repeat Password: </span>
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="rep_pass" />
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
    $(".password_insert").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
            var x = $('#ins_pass').val();
            var y = x.length();
            if (x < 6) {
                $("#error").show();
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/1Ljv4c1x/)

Comment: Console errors? jQuery loaded properly?

Comment: Off topic: Your `<br />` tags are malformed.

Comment: I mean the dialog show's but nothing happens when i press Ok, no matter what the length of the entered password is. ALSO: the span is hidden at the beginning, but i didn't put the style tag in my question :).

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function

Comment: You'll want to make the browser console your first stop with JS issues.

Comment: i don't get what you say :(. Could you explain more clearly where my code is wrong, and what should i change ?

Comment: That's what my answer (down there) is for. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser console reports the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function
```

You're using the `length` method incorrectly:

```
var y = x.length();
```

should be

```
var y = x.length;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/1Ljv4c1x/2)

Also, off topic: Use labels with `for` attributes rather than span tags for accessibility.